# How to outset faces in geometry nodes

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, transforms

So essentially I need to scale edges so that the offset after transformation is constant distance away from original geometry (something like the opposite of inset). I need it to be procedural, so it has to be done using a combination of modifiers and geo-nodes. Is it possible?

If i just use the scale elements node i get:
[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Try this addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vu0MRcq61I https://blenderartists.org/t/offset-edges/584283/397

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Brief description of working principle:

You calculate the normal for edges that are parallel to the faces, and then offset the vertices along the average direction of the neighboring edges.