# geometry nodes, OutSET faces

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

[How to outset faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294088/how-to-outset-faces-in-geometry-nodes)

hi, I'd like to use this GN but it's not working properly in the situation below :

[image]

[image]

it works fine on flat planes or geometry without any hole on it.

But as you can see below, some of the shapes, loose some of their faces. (Side faces)

[image]

[image]

This GN, first separate top part of the mesh from the bottom (based on the selection )

[image]

but when it want to join with other part, it uses this selection which isn't work properly.

[image]

it needs a better selection method.

[image: Geometry node setup]

[image]